# correct resource path for cfn-hup with aws-cdk and launch-template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

All the examples I found were for LaunchConfiguration together with cfn-hup. But I want to use

- a LaunchTemplate, that has
- an AutoScalingGroup
- which has a CloudFormationInit applied to it and
- a CapacityProvider

Normally, you would use `path=Resources.ECSLaunchConfiguration.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init`.

What is the correct path with my setup? My tries failed.
Is there an alternative for cfn-hup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the logical ids:

```
f"path=Resources{self.get_logical_id(self.autoscaling_group.node.default_child)}.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init"
```